# OrderBy does not work with GroupBy in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I want to order my data by id ,but its does not works.
AngularJS version - 1.6 
My HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in gamesList | orderBy: 'cats[0].id' | groupBy: 'cats[0].title'"> 
   ...
</div>
```

My Data is simple object , very big and its get update on scroll .
Also I try (toArray:true) ,but it kills website , so slowly .

How can do this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try with,

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in gamesList | orderBy: 'id' | groupBy: 'title'"> 
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your json of gamesList

Comment: You need to write groupBy filter , check here https://plnkr.co/edit/wyPi10?p=preview